# I get a duplicate empty file when I try to read the original

Tags: file, vba, post, csv

My goal is to send a file from vba to an url and that is almost done but I am getting, for me, a nonsense problem which is what follows.

I create a csv file totally correct and when I try to open and read it using the next code:

```
sFileName = "C:\Users\user\1.csv"
 Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
 If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
 End If
 Close nFile
```

I am getting a duplicate empty file with the same name "1.csv" and that is the one that got sent, so finally I am sending nothing. I am not able to find the problem. I would apreciate it a lot if you could help me with that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some lines, and it worked:

```
Public Sub test()

Dim sFileName As String
Dim nFile As Long
Dim sPostData As String

sFileName = "D:\File1.csv"
nFile = FreeFile

 Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As #nFile
 If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
 End If
 Close nFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just writing the answer. I had already the lines that you send me, the problem was the one I post, nothing wrong with this code nor with the one of before.

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I got it! This code that I just posted is totally correct, the problem was that when I was saving the file with other macro I was saving it with a space on the front so that is why when this macro was trying to open it and reading it, did not find it so it was creating an empty file with the name that I actually wanted.

uf!! god! :)